# Import Error when importing requests in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, importerror, urllib3

I'm trying to run a python program where I run

```
from pycocotools.coco import COCO        
import requests
```

I use Python 3.11.1. It throws ImportError

```
C:\path>python utils.py --img_out obj/ --label_out obj/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .selectors import (
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping

ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

I installed the requests module via pip

Comment: @mousetail: Other way around: they've got a new Python and an old `urllib3` version.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I already tried that, does not help

Comment: Update your urllib3.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @user2357112 's comment.

`pip3 install --upgrade urllib3` solved it.